# High Trust S2S Provider Hosted App with "App + User" Policy

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

I am relatively new to sharepoint app development.

Trying to create a on premises, High Trust provider hosted app with App + User Policy. I have followed below document to create a demo.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/fp179901(v=office.15)
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2014/06/23/part-1-intro-to-provider-hosted-apps-setup-the-infrastructure.aspx

I am facing few issue and I have some question to clarify, if anybody can help.

1) When I inspect my request in dev tools, it give me below form data.

> SPAppToken:
>
> SPSiteUrl:
>
> SPSiteTitle:Home
>
> SPSiteLogoUrl:
>
> SPSiteLanguage:en-US
>
> SPSiteCulture:en-US
>
> SPRedirectMessage:EndpointAuthorityMatches
>
> SPErrorCorrelationId:f069e89c-a0cd-20ce-a1c0-7db95db0334b

now when i inspect log with above corelation id, i am finding below errors.

> *-- Error when get token for app i:0i.t|ms.sp.ext|ab8ff461-bc75-4516-b475-b666ac47eec0@802f23e1-6e11-45d1-909c-07a7b0ab0ce2,
>   exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The Azure Access Control
>   service is unavailable.
>
>   -- App token requested from appredirect.aspx for site: 92bfe5c4-7255-4b09-a89a-07e0e2b03622 but there was an error in
>   generating it.  This may be a case when we do not need a token or when
>   the app principal was not properly set up.
>   -- Getting Error Message for Exception Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The Azure Access Control service is
>   unavailable.*

a) I belive in high-trust app it shouldn't look for Azure ACS.
Is this error because of some incorrect configuration?
b) SPAppToken is null here. Is it null always in case of hig trust app?

2) Say I am logged into sharepoint with User A and trying to launch sharepoint app. 
Within app code I want to get identity of logged in user(which is A). From below code i found that Request.LogonUserIdentity gives me identity of user A. But how can we sure that request is came from sharepoint only. I can copy the same app URL and paste in browser window and login with window credential and get the same result. So question is how can I verify if its legitimate request came from sharepoint only and no one is faking request.
ALos, when I inspect request in dev tools, its passing Authorization key in request header. What is use of this?

```
using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(hostWeb, Request.LogonUserIdentity))             {                    clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, web => web.Title);                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();                   Response.Write(clientContext.Web.Title);             }
```

3) Also what happens if my app doesnt support windows authentication and only support FBA, is there any way to get user identity in this case?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this issue? I am facing the similar issue and in my case, I am getting "The Azure Access Control service is unavailable." error for my OnPerm SharePoint 2016 environment.

Answer (score 1):

For issue #1: It looks to me that the step # 9 (Configure authentication settings) in [this section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/fp179901(v=office.15)#Createapp2) (from the first MSDN article you have referred) was missed, i.e., 'ACS Control service' was selected instead of 'Use a Certificate' option.

For issue #2: There are helper methods in TokenHelper.cs to validate the AccessToken from the HttpRequest, which identifies the validity of the request.